# Resize objects in view while opening sidebar/menu Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view, sidebar

I am currently programming the app with side bar/menu and I would like to leave some functions from the view which is partially hidden when the side bar is opened. I was thinking about resizing/transitioning/disappearing of some objects from the main view while opening the side bar from right

For example, the main view/page is hidden I would like to resize some things so they still can be clickable and functional and when you drag it back the normal view appears again

I guess it mostly looks like a new view with animation, but I didn't find the way how to implement that and therefore I decided to do with sidebar. Could you tell me please, how to make the view changeable according to sidebar and make some objects appear instead of simply have partial information on that side?

Here is the actual application:

The [main view is just with coverArts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxVSc.jpg) (first in the middle and second is in the bottom) and when dragging/opening the side bar the first cover resizes according to slide movement and second bottom cover just goes directly. Then it should look like on the [second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siy9R.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

========= ADD OBSERVER IN VIEW WILL APPEAR    =======

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourVC.showOverlayView), name: Notification.Name("showOverlayView"), object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourVC.hideOverlayView), name: Notification.Name("hideOverlayView"), object: nil)
```

========= You can Hide and Show From Here    =======

```
func showOverlayView() {
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
            self.viewBlackOverLay     = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height))
            self.viewBlackOverLay.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
            self.view.addSubview(self.viewBlackOverLay)
        })
    }

func hideOverlayView() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        self.viewBlackOverLay.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}
```

========= POST OBSERVER   =======

When you want to Open side menu add below Line

**NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "showOverlayView"), object: nil)**

Where you close side menu add below Line

**NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "hideOverlayView"), object: nil)**